# Accessing UI Thread Window from another thread and class for AAD WIndow

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a WPF that prompts the user to login to Azure AD, and I am unable to get the call to fire, instead it hangs the UI thread. Here is the code that I am trying to call

```
 authResult = _application.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                          .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle)
                          .ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

I have tried wrapping this in a dispatcher call, like so

```
internal static Dispatcher GetDispatcher(this DispatcherObject source)
{
    //use the application's dispatcher by default
    if (Application.Current != null) return Application.Current.Dispatcher;

    //fallback for WinForms environments
    if (source.Dispatcher != null) return source.Dispatcher;

    // ultimately use the thread's dispatcher
    return Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}

var dispatcher = MainWindow.main.GetDispatcher();

if (!dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    var action = new Action(() => {
        authResult = _application.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                     .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle)
                     .ExecuteAsync().Result;
        });
        dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
        return;
}
```

If I move the interactive call in my MainWindow.xaml.cs, it works fine, but I want to move it to a service class to clean things up. What could I be doing wrong? The above code is in a function that has a signature like this

```
 public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
```

I can provide additional info if needed.

Comment: `ExecuteAsync().Result` this looks strange( and potentially dangerous) on a few levels. If you use the *async and await pattern* all the way down, you wont have to call `Result`, and it will create a continuation on the *UI thread*

Comment: This is just a guess but I think your dispatcher varies when called from a service. Make sure you use Application Dispatcher to ensure you are using the UI dispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_application.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                          .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle)
                          .ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

Calling Result will block the UI thread. 
Instead, you need to await the call.

```
await _application.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                          .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle)
                          .ExecuteAsync();
```

You will need to mark the function `async` as well.

Comment: Thanks, so if the code that calls this is something like

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Now have issues with the call being made twice, but I think that is an issue somewhere else. Marking this as answer.

Answer (score -1):

Check out juunas's solution. Also if you decide to put that code in a library consider using .ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid undesired scenario. [This link](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f) talks about it with some examples.